# Allocate more RAM without re-compiling

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I've got an old application for 32-bit Windows XP which is only able to allocate 2GB of RAM on my 64bit Windows 10 system. As this application tries to use more than 2GB RAM when storing a lot of data, I'm getting an Out of Memory Exception like this one:

> `Out of memory
>       8 addresses:
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+825384 (unknown)
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+798965 (unknown)
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+793330 (unknown)
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+793277 (unknown)
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+799637 (unknown)
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+666356 (unknown)
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+664774 (unknown)
>       (unknown)(0): Worldbuilder.exe+723505 (unknown) 
>   Because of the severity of this error the game will now exit.`
>
> **Note:** The source code of the application is not available.

I also saw some tools which fix this problem by allowing the application to allocate up to 4GB of RAM **without** having to re-compile the application, like [Large Address Aware](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/large-address-aware.112556/).

My question is now:
How are those tools able to achieve this.

> **Note:** I'm using Windows 10 64bit with the programming languages C++/C. I also do not have any code yet as I do not even know how this works in theory.

Comment: It is just a single bit in the [executable file header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313(v=vs.85).aspx), flipping on IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE is all it takes.  Takes 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets the large-address-aware flag in the executable's Win32PE header. This is normally set at link time. The application may not actually be able to handle a memory allocation greater than 2G if it uses signed 32-bit values to index into those allocations.